# Get full qualified type for variable in scala REPL

Tags: scala, collections, types, read-eval-print-loop

I run scala repl create simple value with `Set` function and try to figure out what flavor of Set was created.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3-20130923-000000-e2fec6b28d (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val s = Set(0,3,1)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(0, 3, 1)

scala> :type s
scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]

scala> s.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set3
```

That does make thing clear for me. I read scaladoc for the Set and found out that `Set` is a generic trait that may have different concrete implementations.

So what implementation of the set trait was used this time inside REPL? How can I figure it out without deeping in scala source code and performing other complicated tasks? It would be perfect if searching the type would require only REPL itself.

I get confused out of nothing. Set3 is a valid class name, not a sort of garbage. So, the right way to determine class:

```
scala> val s = Range(0,1000).toSet
scala> s.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet
```

With that the answer should be closed

Comment: I don't understand the question. Doesn't the s.getClass tell you that the set type is scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set3?

Comment: @rancidfishbreath [**it is**](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L130), but likely ayvango expected something like HashSet or LinkedHashSet, but was confused with such weird naming, I think you got the idea.

Comment: You can read the scaladoc for Set3. It would be interesting to have a verbose command that summarized the characteristics of the collection you're working with.